# Displaying date depending if it's last day in the month with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem with displaying correct date. I want to display tommorow date if today is the last day in the month, and time is 20:00 PM and more.

I've tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355063/how-to-validate-date-if-is-the-last-day-of-the-month-with-javascript), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript) and [this](https://output.jsbin.com/emoto4/4) but nothing worked for me.

```
function isLastDay(dt) {
      return new Date(dt.getTime() + 86400000).getDate() === 1;
  }
```

```js
function changeDay() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) + 3);
  d.setDate(31);
  d.setHours(20);
  var day = d.getDate();
  var hrs = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var sec = d.getSeconds();

  var dayString = 'today';

  var mnt = new Array("january", "february", "march", "april", "may",
    "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december");
  var lastday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();

  if (((hrs == 19) && (min > 45)) || (hrs > 19)) {
    day = day + 1;
    dayString = 'tomorrow';
  }

  if (day === lastday) {
    $(".start-web").html(day + " " + mnt[d.getMonth() + 1, 0]);
  } else {
    $(".start-web").html(day + " " + mnt[d.getMonth()]);
  }

  $(".start-web-d").html(dayString);
}

setInterval("changeDay()", 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>
      Start 
      <span class="start-web-d">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
      <span class="start-web">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
      20:00 
    </strong>
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My script shows me 32 of January, for example, and my purpose is to show 1 of February. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the [link to my example](https://codepen.io/MegaZef/pen/VqNPJM).

Comment: You're adding `1` as an integer to `day` if the hours is between the range in the condition. Don't do that. Add a day to the Date object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic should be all you need: if tomorrow is day 1 then today is the last day of the month, and if the date `getHours` method returns 20 or greater you should have met your criteria.

```js
const dt = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date(dt.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000).getDate();

if (tomorrow === 1 && dt.getHours() >= 20) {
  console.log('criteria met!');
} else {
  console.log(dt, tomorrow);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the lastday variable there, but I cannot see how you are using it. You need to have something check to see if the current date is the 31st.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the the `===` operator with `>=`

```
if (day >= lastday) {
  $(".start-web").html(day + " " + mnt[d.getMonth() + 1, 0]);
} else {
  $(".start-web").html(day + " " + mnt[d.getMonth()]);
}
```

#### Explanation

Before this line:

```
if (((hrs == 19) && (min > 45)) || (hrs > 19))
```

Your `day` value is `31`, and then it adds the `day` value by `1` because the condition is met, so that after the if else scope, the `day` value is `32`

Then you compare `day` which is `32` with `lastday` which is `31`, therefore the condition is not met and showed `32 January` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The last Day of the month at 20:00PM is the same as the 1st day of the month -4 hours we can use that to create a function to check to see if we are past that date:

```
function lastMinus4(){
  let now = new Date();
  let lastM4 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1, -4);

  return (now > lastM4);  
}
```

the now variable is the current date and time, the lastM4 is the current year, the current month + 1 which is next month, the 1 is the first day of the month, and the -4 is 4 hours in the past which is the last day of the month at 20:00PM.  Another way would be to use the day as -1, and add set the hour to 20.

In the Date constructor you have above using 0 as the day gives you the last day of the previous month, so just add 20 at the end of the constructor for the hours and you have the time to check now against.