# get current date and time in javascript for given lat long

Tags: javascript

I develop a coupon application using javascript, am new to this. I need to get the current date and time for given lat and long position in javascript. Anybody know,kindly suggest me. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using `getUTCTime()` (see [MDN's `Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)), and then using an offset.

Comment: The askers problem here is determining THE offset using lat and long :)

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, determine the timezone (see [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)) and translate the current UTC time?