# Retrieve the last day of the year in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Today it's 06/11/2012.
I need retrieve the last day of the current year using javascript.

```
function getLastDayOfYear(date)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = 0; // ?????

    x.innerHTML = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
}
```

Is there any function that retrieve it done, or must i do a full implementation?
If i need to implement this, could anyone help me out ?

I made a simple fiddle you can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/EyzCD/

Comment: Isn't the last day of the year always 31-12-[year]?

Comment: the last day of the year is always December 31.  Why would you need to calculate that?

Comment: @Jason In case of it changes...

Comment: Well, the world is ending in 2012, as we all know, so he needs to get the last day of the year from the Mayan calendar.

Comment: You will find the answer [here][1] on the stackoverflow.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript

Comment: @sp00m: We've pretty much got the [calendar figured out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) at this point; I very much doubt that we'll change the length of December.

Comment: Lol thx, i forgot that 31 is the last day D:

Comment: hehe, check this: http://davidlongstreet.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/dont-drink-and-code/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Since the last day of a year is always December 31, it's easy:

```
new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31)
```

Answer (score 8):

In case that someday the last day of the year changes, could be useful to use a temporary date with the first day on the next month and then return to the previous date

```
tmp_date = new Date(2012, 12, 1)
last_day = new Date(tmp_date - 1)
```

Comment: Alternatively: `last_day = new Date(new Date(2012, 12, 1) - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

This will return Last day of Year

```
var actualDate = new Date()
var eoYear = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(),12,0)
```

In case if you need to return Last second of the year

```
var actualDate = new Date()
var eoYear = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(),12,0,23,59,59)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(new Date(2012, 12, 0));
```

will return

```
Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 CST 20102
```

Comment: If you pass 11 it will return the Nov month. :) try it. It's the reason why I passed the zero value as the third parameter. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Will this do it for you? 
This will return the Whole lot for you to pick from.

```
function LastDayOfMonth(Year, Month) {
   return new Date( (new Date(Year, Month,1))-1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to get last day of the month.

try:

```
var tmp = new Date(year, month+1, 1);
var days = new Date(tmp-1).getDate();
```