# Dynamically change dates in a paragraph with Java Script (need cross browser solution)

Tags: javascript, datetime, inline, innerhtml

I created a sweepstakes official rules pop-up that automatically updates the date when the month changes. It works perfectly, except in IE, ugh! So I am trying to make java script changes in a  span tag for just the dynamic content, but I hit a snag. I know I need to use innerHTML and configure with an id, but I am not sure how to implement it. here is my all-java generated pop-up: http://images.zales.com/images/CMSImages/angelaspeed/test/rw_sweeps.html (remember it doesn't work in IE).

Secondly, I have not found an effective way to generate the last day of the month to use in my inline code, therefore you will see "last day of" month + year used. If you have a solution, Please let me know.

Thanks Gurus, Love Ms. Novice

Comment: What version of IE and does the console show any error(s)?

Comment: I am on a mac and am required to support 7+. I have crossover and it shows up, but my colleagues on PC say it does not render.

Comment: I ran your URL through [http://netrenderer.com/index.php](http://netrenderer.com/index.php) and it I was able to see the dates in red for versions 6-10 of IE. Did they say it was blank? Or did it render incorrectly?

Comment: they said all they could see was the non-javascript generated text (starting with Colorado Disclosure Box).

Comment: OH, so the issue is not specifically with the `date` portion, everything in `document.write` is failing for them. I know this sounds ridiculous, but is there any chance they have Javascript turned off?

Comment: That is possible, but I need to have this viewable for the general public and can't tell them to "enable Java Script to view" Any help available on my second question??

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript)

Comment: AND if I need next month's first mid or last date? Shouldn't I bea able to use this? lastdate = new Date(y, (m + 1,) 0).getDate(); changing the 0 to the 1, 15 or 0? I think I'm over simplifying.

Comment: that specific code creates a conflict and renders none of my java generated text in any browser (even just adding the variable, with my scripts). to get around it, I defined separate month, day and year elements and put them together like: +  months[month_value] + " 1, "  + year_value + but still would rather generate the number only of the last day of the month instead of having to say, "the last day of " + months[month_value] + ", "  + year_value +

Answer (score 1):

**`new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()`** returns the date of the last day of the month, where m is a an integer between 1 and 12 and y is the 4 digit year.

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date(),

    firstOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1),
    midMonth     = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 15),
    lastOfMonth  = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);

   document.write(firstOfMonth + "<br/>" + midMonth + "<br/>" + lastOfMonth);
```

In response to comments from OP above.