# Set a trigger to run function the last hour of each month

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In google scripts I know there are triggers to run by date, but I don't think that will work because month's have different amounts of days. So I was wondering if there's a way to set a trigger to run at 11PM on the last night of each month, no matter if that's a 30 or a 31.

Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript) kind of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a trigger from project *Edit > current project's trigger* or register it programmatically that will run every day at 11 pm.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myTriggerFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .atHour(23)
   .everyDays(1) 
   .create();
```

Then in your trigger handler, check if today is the last day of the month, then do your work.

```
function myTriggrFunction()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);

  if(today.getDate() == lastDayOfMonth.getDate() )
  {
    // your work to be done
  }
}
```