# Convert MMM YY string to date javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a value `JUN 16` as string. I need to convert it to a date object. I need to find out last date of the month JUNE year 2016.

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a free code writing service, there are many questions and answers here on parsing date strings. Whatever you do, don't parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing). You can use a library to parse the string, there are plenty of good ones out there, or write a small (3 line) function to parse the format MMM YY. There are also plenty of questions and good answers on getting the number of days in a month, or setting a date to the last day of the month. Have a go and post what you've tried if you can't work it out.

Comment: See [*Calculate last day of month in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am converting a **Date("MMM-YY")** to **Date("YYYY-MM-DD")**

**Input** : `Nov-17`

**run** : `new Date("Nov-17")`

**Output** : `Sat Nov 17 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

> now by adding a prefix to your date like below

**input** : `1-Nov-17 //add prefix to your string '1-'`

**run** : `new Date("1-Nov-2017")`

**output**: `Wed Nov 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

> Moment

**run** : `moment("1-Nov-17").endOf('month').format("YYYY-MM-DD") //End day of the month`

**output**: `"2017-11-30"`

Comment: This does not work on FireFox. Chrome Only

Answer (score 0):

> I have a value "JUN 16" as string .I need to convert to date object

This is how you do it:

```
var date = new Date(2016, 5, 16);
console.log(date);
```

> i need to find out last date of the month JUNE year 2016

And this is how you can do that:

```
// 5 is June
var date = new Date(2016,  5 + 1, 0);
console.log(date.getDay())
```

This tells you that the day is `4` which is "Thursday"

Comment: I've edited my answer sorry didn't realize it didn't work on safari. This should work cross browser.

Comment: Cool. There's no need to include a date argument for *new Date*, year and month (number) are sufficient. ;-)