# setDate doesn't return the last day of the month Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I expect 31 because this month October has 31 days, which part of my code is wrong here?

```
function lastDayOfMonth(given_month) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(0);
  d.setMonth(given_month);
  return d.toISOString();
}

console.log(lastDayOfMonth(given_month))
```

> 2016-10-30T13:16:14.227Z

Comment: i think this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript

Comment: Don´t worry, it fails today, but tomorrow will work :P (it´s true!!, but going to put a response)

Comment: @sergio0983 yes sometimes it happens haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d.setDate(0);
```

sets the date to the last day of the previous month. I.e if you run this script in October, the date will be set to Sep 30.

Afterwards you run

```
d.setMonth(given_month);
```

This sets the month, but leaves the day of month as it is. I assume that given_month is  9 (i.e. Oct), so this will result in Oct 30.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate for more info.

Comment: given_month value is 9, which means Oct. But isn't Oct has 31 days?

Comment: `var d = new Date();` creates a new date object with current date/time. `d.setDate(0);` sets the date to the last day of the previous month, i.e. to Sep 30. `d.setMonth(given_month);` sets the month to Oct, but doesn't change the day of month, ie this is still 30. So your resulting date is Oct 30.

Comment: I still don't get it. My current date now is Oct 30. Please tell me why last day of the month of Oct is 30.

Comment: Because `d.setDate(0)` changes to the last day of the _previous_ month. If you still don't get it you should debug your function step by step, examining how your date object changes after each statement.

Comment: so what should I do now? I just want to get the last day of a month, given given_month is a variable.

Comment: 1. For example `d.setMonth(given_month + 1); d.setDate(0);`. 2. Examine what happens in December with that code. 3. Read a book about how to learn programming

Comment: Use `d.setMonth(given_month + 1, 0);`. This will work. Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hvn7kjso/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
given_month = 10;

function lastDayOfMonth(given_month) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(15);
  d.setMonth(given_month);
  d.setDate(0)
  return d.toISOString();
}

console.log(lastDayOfMonth(given_month)) // 2016-10-30T13:16:14.227Z
```

Expl:  Today is 31, so, new Date set day to 31; when you set month to 10 (November), day is still 31, but November only has 30 days, hence the error.

Comment: Expl. added; note that 15 could be any number below 30

Comment: how to get current month but last day? like 31 Oct 2016? I passed given_month as 9. I get the month right but not the last day, it suppose to be 31 not 30. What should I do

Answer (score 0):

setDate(0) will yield the last day of the previous month

Comment: I should do setDate(1) ?

Comment: this month is oct, and I expect 31. But I got 30?

Comment: Nope. If you want to get the last day of the current month, do `d.setMonth(given_month+1)`

Comment: No, this will give me November 30