# How do you change the time from the code in Datpicker?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I would like to choose a date, then convert it to the last day of the month and display it in the datpicker? Has anyone done something like that already? 
I have been struggling for two days and I still have not found the problem solved. 
The problem concerns the display itself and in the datepicker. 
If anyone has an idea, I am asking for an example of virtue.

Comment: It depends on which Datepicker you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use native datepickers (html) to make your life easier. Once you have it, it will run everywhere (desktop, web or phone apps)

[Click here to see a working example with datepickers on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/f8sr1aug/)

```
const $origin_day = document.querySelector('label:first-of-type > input')
const $last_day = document.querySelector('label:last-of-type > input')

$origin_day.onchange = () => {
  if (!$origin_day.value) return;

  const date = new Date($origin_day.value)
  $last_day.value = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1)
    .toISOString().slice(0, 10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can basically write in plan JS you should take a look at this [Thread on how to get last day of previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You didn't tell us which datepicker you are using but assuming it's Material Datepicker, using Reactive forms, it goes like this:

```
JS:    this.editForm.controls['dateTo'].setValue(yourDate);
        HTML:
         <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerTo" placeholder="Choose a date" id="cmp_dateEndField" 
                            [formControl]="dateTo">
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker #pickerTo></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: I use the whole project https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datepicker