# How to get 1st and last date of a Month and Year where Month Is in Alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textbox` in which date is coming as **March 2016** 
.now I want 1st and last date of that Month.

Comment: I guess the first date of the month is always starts with 1? So in your case, it would be March 1, 2016. When getting the last date of the month I guess you can refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can pass month name as string

```
var year = 2018;
var sMonthName = "March"; 
var iMonthNo = new Date(sMonthName + "01, "+year).getMonth(); 
var FirstDay = new Date(year, iMonthNo, 1);
var LastDay = new Date(year, iMonthNo + 1, 0);

console.log(FirstDay);
console.log(LastDay);
```

UPDATE:

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gtKeL/82/

```
var date = document.getElementById("txtDate").value.split(" ");
var year = date[1];
var sMonthName = date[0]; 
var iMonthNo = new Date(sMonthName + "01, "+year).getMonth(); 
var FirstDay = new Date(year, iMonthNo, 1);
var LastDay = new Date(year, iMonthNo + 1, 0);

console.log(FirstDay);
console.log(LastDay);
```

Comment: how to seprate Month and Year from text box ?

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can help you , you dont need any library,try it

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

by the way,some browsers only treat two digits for years

Comment: i have the month and Year in the Textbox i want to get 1st and last date of the month by that !!

Comment: read the values from textbox and pass to the function

Comment: well,after you set to 2016,you can show firstDay and lastDay variables in your textbox like this :  var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
textbox3.value=answer;

Answer (score 0):

http://www.encodedna.com/javascript/first-and-last-day-of-a-given-month-in-javascript.htm

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get The First and Last Day of a Given Month</title>
</head>

<body>
   <body>
<input type="date" id="dt" onchange="mydate1();" onmouseout="getTheDays()" hidden/>
<input type="text" id="ndt"  onclick="mydate();" onmouseout="getTheDays()" hidden />
<input type="button" Value="Date" onclick="mydate();" onmouseout="getTheDays()" />

    <p>First Day of the Month: <label id="fday"></label></p>
    <p>Last Day of the Month: <label id="lday"></label></p>
</body>

<script>
  
  function mydate()
{
  //alert("");
document.getElementById("dt").hidden=false;
document.getElementById("ndt").hidden=true;
}
function mydate1()
{
 d=new Date(document.getElementById("dt").value);
dt=d.getDate();
mn=d.getMonth();
mn++;
yy=d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("ndt").value=mn+"/"+yy
document.getElementById("ndt").hidden=false;
document.getElementById("dt").hidden=true;
}
    function getTheDays() {

        // THE DATE OBJECT.

        var dt = new Date(document.getElementById('dt').value );

        // GET THE MONTH AND YEAR OF THE SELECTED DATE.
        var month = dt.getMonth(),
            year = dt.getFullYear();

        // GET THE FIRST AND LAST DATE OF THE MONTH.
        var FirstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
        var LastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);

        // FINALLY, GET THE DAY.
        var weekday = new Array();
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        if (typeof weekday[FirstDay.getDay()] != 'undefined') {     // CHECK FOR 'undefined'.
            document.getElementById('fday').innerHTML = weekday[FirstDay.getDay()] +
                ' (' + FirstDay.toDateString('dd/mon/yyyy') + ')';
            document.getElementById('lday').innerHTML = weekday[LastDay.getDay()] +
                ' (' + LastDay.toDateString('dd/mon/yyyy') + ')'; ;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('fday').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('lday').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i am getting Input as March 2016  Feb 2016

Comment: Add only getTheDays () to your code and it will work.

Comment: in  your textbox add onmouseout="getTheDays()"

Comment: @Shrey Right now ,it works with only input mm yyyy