# React Native How Get first and last date of current month to DatePicker

Tags: react-native

how get first day and last day current month in React Native to my DatePicker

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
    modalVisible: false,
    date:new Date(),
    minfecha: '',
    maxfecha: '',
    isLoading: false,
},
this.setState({
    minfecha: new Date(this.state.date.getFullYear(), this.state.date.getMonth(), 1),
    maxfecha: new Date(this.state.date.getFullYear(), this.state.date.getMonth() + 1, 0)
});
}
```

Comment: don't is duplicate, i need to React Native

Comment: The code for calculating the last day of the month is the same in React Native as it is anywhere else; it's still JavaScript.

Comment: you can teach me how set the first and last day of the month correctly?

Comment: @DeshBourne Have you already tried what says on the previously given link? ([Calculate last day of month in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript))

Comment: yeas i tried but give error set this states in my react native app

Comment: @DeshBourne can you post the error message that you are receiving?