# The simultaneous criteria in JavaScript switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, criteria

Instead of writing like "28 or 29 days", how can we add also the leap-year check to switch, to get 29 days for the year 2000?

```
var month = "Feb";
var year = 2000;
switch(month) {
    case "Apr": case "Jun": case "Sep": case "Nov":
    console.log("30 days."); break;
case "Feb":
    console.log("28 or 29 days."); break;
default: console.log("31 days.");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate last day of month in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you. Code should be self explanatory. Please let me know.

```js
function isLeapYear(year) {
  return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

function getMonthLength(month, year) {
  switch(month) {
    case "Apr": case "Jun": case "Sep": case "Nov":
      return 30;
    case "Feb":
      return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    default:
      return 31;
  }
}

console.log(getMonthLength('Feb', 2000));
console.log(getMonthLength('Jan', 2001));
console.log(getMonthLength('Feb', 2001));
console.log(getMonthLength('Sep', 2001));
```

Comment: Dear Ernesto, your answer works seamlessly, thanks. Later I post the question, I find a solution by myself, but yours is better.

Comment: @AhmetArduç I'm glad to hear that. Please remember to mark this question as answered if you think we're done here.

Answer (score -1):

Knowing that 2020 was a leap year
write a function like this

```js
 var findLeap = ()=> {
    var dateYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var leap = dateYear - 2020
 
    if (leap % 4 == 0){
      console.log('Its another Leap year')
  }else{
      console.log('Its NOT a Leap year')
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ogoh-cyril, I asked the question to learn how to use the switch with two parameters. Thanks for your reply.