# Get first day and last day in Month, Week and work week

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a problem to get first day and last day in Month, Week and work week for JavaScript code.

For example selected date is 04/02/2022 (mm/dd/yyyy).
The actual result will come out like below:

1. Month (First day is 04/01/2022, last day is 04/30/2022)
2. Week (First day is Sunday 03/27/2022 , last day is Saturday 04/02/2022)
3. Work Week (First day is Monday 03/28/2022 , last day is Friday 04/01/2022)

This is my sample code:

```js
//Get Month first day and last day. For example if date is 04/02/2022 (mm/dd/yyyy), the last day will show 04/01/2022 and the last day will show 04/30/2022

let selected_date = "Sat Apr 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)";
let date = selected_date();
let firstDay = selected_date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
let lastDay = selected_date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0); 
let selectedFirstDateCheck = moment(firstDay).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
let selectedLastDateCheck = moment(lastDay).format('MM/DD/YYYY');        
console.log ("First date:" + selectedFirstDateCheck + " Last date:" + selectedLastDateCheck);

//Get Week first day and last day. For example if date is Saturday 04/02/2022 (mm/dd/yyyy), the last day will show Sunday 03/27/2022 and the last day will show Saturday 04/02/2022
let curr = = "Sat Apr 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)";
let  first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
let last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

let firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
let lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();

console.log ("First date:" + firstday + " Last date:" + lastday);


//Get Work Week first day and last day. For example if date is Saturday 04/02/2022 (mm/dd/yyyy), the last day will show Monday 03/28/2022 and the last day will show Friday 04/01/2022

let selected_date = "Sat Apr 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)";
let firstday = new Date(selected_date.setDate(selected_date.getDate() - selected_date.getDay())).toUTCString();
let lastday = new Date(selected_date.setDate(selected_date.getDate() - selected_date.getDay() + 7)).toUTCString();
console.log ("First date:" + firstday + " Last date:" + lastday);
```

My codes result doesn't work to get the actual answer, anyone can guide me on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: In your code, you define `selected_date` as a string, and then in the next line try to call it as a function. What is `selected_date` actually supposed to do?

Comment: selected_date is customized date what I want

Comment: How is this issue React related?

Comment: @cheesyMan Sorry,  I have edited it.

Comment: There are LOTs of duplicates of these questions. Also please don't ask multiple questions at the same time. If you google each one of those I'm sure you'll find answers for these problems on previous SO questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate last day of month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month)

Comment: As @JoshG pointed, `selected_date` is defined as a string in the first line, but then is called as a function in the second line. Obviously you cannot "execute" a string :). Can you clarify?

Comment: @Liam Google more about current date to get month, week, work week date. Not selected date.