Issue with Date Calculation outside of getting lastday of the month
I'm sending a string with an amount, and date as you can see...BUT when the data comes back for Transactions Created from a single Transaction with a Monthly Reocurrance...ALL months are fine...and LastDay works...however, there is never a Feb...and I'm not sure why Feb is being skipped?
I've entered feburary manually as a one-time and the month appears...but for somereason the iteration of adding Transactions for Reoccurances seems to have issues. Can someone please point out what I may be missing?
import axios from 'axios';
import './AddTransactionModals.css'; // Add your custom styles here

interface AddTransactionModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const AddTransactionModal: React.FC<AddTransactionModalProps> = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    type: 'Expense',
    title: '',
    amount: '',
    date: '',
    reocurrance: 'one-time',
    enddate: '',
    creditTransId: '',
    notes: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const getLastDayOfMonth = (year: number, month: number) => {
    return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
  };

  const adjustToLastDayOfMonth = (date: Date) => {
    const lastDay = getLastDayOfMonth(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
    const adjustedDate = new Date(date);
    adjustedDate.setDate(Math.min(date.getDate(), lastDay -1));
    return adjustedDate;
  };

  const calculateRecurringDates = (startDate: Date, recurrence: string, endDate: Date) => {
    const dates: Date[] = [];
    let currentDate = new Date(startDate);

    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
      let adjustedDate = adjustToLastDayOfMonth(currentDate);
      if (adjustedDate > endDate) break;

      dates.push(new Date(adjustedDate));

      switch (recurrence) {
        case 'weekly':
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7);
          break;
        case 'bi-weekly':
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14);
          break;
        case 'monthly':
          // Increment month and adjust day
          currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
          currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
          currentDate = adjustToLastDayOfMonth(currentDate);
          break;
        case 'bi-monthly':
          // Increment month by 2 and adjust day
          currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 2);
          currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
          currentDate = adjustToLastDayOfMonth(currentDate);
          break;
        case 'yearly':
          // Increment year and adjust day
          currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1);
          currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
          currentDate = adjustToLastDayOfMonth(currentDate);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    return dates;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const endOfYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31); // End of current year
    let endDate = formData.enddate ? new Date(formData.enddate) : endOfYear;

    const startDate = new Date(formData.date);
    const recurrenceDates = formData.reocurrance !== 'one-time'
      ? calculateRecurringDates(startDate, formData.reocurrance, endDate)
      : [startDate];

    try {
      const requests = recurrenceDates.map(date => {
        const transactionData = {
          ...formData,
          date: date.toISOString().split('T')[0], // Format as YYYY-MM-DD
        };
        return axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/transactions', transactionData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
      });

      await Promise.all(requests);

      console.log('Transactions added successfully');
      onClose(); // Close the modal after submission
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding transaction:', error);
    }
  };

  if (!isOpen) return null;

  return (
    <div className="modal-overlay">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <button className="modal-close" onClick={onClose}>
          &times;
        </button>
        <h2>Add Transaction</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Title:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={formData.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Type:
            <select
              name="type"
              value={formData.type}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <option value="Expense">Expense</option>
              <option value="Payday">Payday</option>
              <option value="Credit Card Payment">Credit Card Payment</option>
              <option value="Placeholder">Placeholder</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <label>
            Amount:
            <input
              type="number"
              name="amount"
              value={formData.amount}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Date:
            <input
              type="date"
              name="date"
              value={formData.date}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Recurrence:
            <select
              name="reocurrance"
              value={formData.reocurrance}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <option value="one-time">one-time</option>
              <option value="weekly">weekly</option>
              <option value="bi-weekly">bi-weekly</option>
              <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
              <option value="bi-monthly">bi-monthly</option>
              <option value="yearly">yearly</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          {formData.reocurrance !== 'one-time' && (
            <label>
              End Date:
              <input
                type="date"
                name="enddate"
                value={formData.enddate}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </label>
          )}
          {formData.reocurrance === 'one-time' && (
            <label>
              End Date:
              <input
                type="date"
                name="enddate"
                value={formData.enddate}
                disabled
              />
            </label>
          )}
          <label>
            Notes:
            <textarea
              name="notes"
              value={formData.notes}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Credit Transaction ID:
            <input
              type="number"
              name="creditTransId"
              value={formData.creditTransId}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add Transaction</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
`


You seem to have copied a lot of irrelevant parts of the code in to the question. To answer the problem, if you want to get the last day of a given month, use this logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/222439/519413. If that's not what you're asking, please edit the question to give a much clearer problem statement

that's because I've already used that logic for GET last day of the month...however it skips over Feburary for some reason....So i've included the entire class.  Cause I can't see WHY it would skip over the 2nd month and not any others...

It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/sqLzky5x/. Remember that Jan = 0, Feb = 1, so if you're passing 2 as the Month value then that will be giving you the last day in March

again...look at it...for the rest of the months...it's fine(getLastDayOfMonth)...keep in mind...it get's the date that's populated as a DATE and then fills in data for a year...but for some reason skips over feburary 2025 when the transactions come in.  it's NOT the getLastDayOfMonth that's the problem...something in the rest...isn't letting Feburary populate...I'm not setting the int for which month...it gets it by the string's increment.

when i put console.log(date.getMonth()) in the console and run the transaction...it goes from 0 then two...it completely skips over 1...

Figured it out....it WAS a calculation issue.
the issue is when ADDING another month...you first have to know the next months number of DAYS otherwise...it'll skip over by going to the next month.  SO
        case 'monthly':
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + getLastDayOfMonth(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1));
          break;

